# Tasks created from celery tasks getting created twice

Tags: flask, celery

We are using celery 3.1.17 with redis backend in our flask 0.10.1 application. On our server every celery task created from some celery task is getting created twice. For example,

```
@celery.task(name='send_some_xyz_users_alerts')
def send_some_xyz_users_alerts():
    list_of_users = find_some_list_of_users()
    for user in list_of_users:
        send_user_alert.delay(user)


@celery.task(name='send_user_alert')
def send_user_alert(user):
    data = get_data_for_user(user)
    send_mail_to_user(data)
```

If we start `send_some_xyz_users_alerts` from our application it runs once. I then see 2 `send_user_alert` tasks running in celery for each user. Both these tasks have different task_ids. We have 2 workers running on server. Some times these duplicate tasks run on same worker. Sometimes on different workers. I have tried lot to find the problem without any luck. Would really appreciate if someone knows why this could happen. Things were running fine for months on these versions of celery and flask and suddenly we are seeing this problem on our servers. Tasks run fine on local env.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with redis backend. See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400 and https://blog.daftcode.pl/working-with-asynchronous-celery-tasks-lessons-learned-32bb7495586b.